# .NET SOAP Consumption - 'Could not Unmarshall Type'

Tags: c#, soap, soap-client, unmarshalling

I am attempting to Consume the Voxbone service publicly located here:
http://sandbox.voxbone.com/VoxAPI/services/VoxAPI?wsdl

So what I did was add a new project, right click - Add Service Reference.
From there, a bunch of code was generated and I was given the objects i need.  However, when calling *some* of the functions (some of them work), I receive the error:

```
Could not unmarshall type : cvc-minExclusive-valid: Value '0' is not facet-valid with respect to minExclusive '0' for type 'ID'.
```

I figure it's something to do with the ID Property... but honestly this is very cryptic to me.  I've tried googling but to no avail.  Any insight would be very appreciated.

StackTrace:

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Api.Voxbone.VoxboneService.VoxAPIIntf.GetDIDGroupList(GetDIDGroupListRequest request)
   at Api.Voxbone.VoxboneService.VoxAPIIntfClient.Api.Voxbone.VoxboneService.VoxAPIIntf.GetDIDGroupList(GetDIDGroupListRequest request) in {FileSystem}\Reference.cs:line 7471
   at Api.Voxbone.VoxboneService.VoxAPIIntfClient.GetDIDGroupList(GetDIDGroupList GetDIDGroupList1) in {FileSystem}\Reference.cs:line 7477
   at Api.Voxbone.VBService.GetDIDGroups() in {FileSystem}/VBService.cs:line 60

The '{FileSystem}' was snipped for privacy.
```

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? If you're using .NET 3.0 or above, then you should be using "Add Service Reference", not "Add Web Reference".

Comment: i am using 4.0. And yes, I am using 'Add Service Reference'.  I'll fix my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for `minExclusive` in the WSDL. It's under a comment that says `<!-- RESTRICTIONS -->`.  You'll see `<xsd:minExclusive value="0"/>`, which means the ID cannot be assigned a value of 0 or less (because the minimum value is *exlusive*, so it doesn't include `0`).

One easy *hackish* way to fix this, is to download the WSDL, and change `<xsd:minExclusive value="0"/>` for `<xsd:minExclusive value="-1"/>`, then re-add the web reference to your project pointing to the modified WSDL instead of the original.

The right way to fix it is to figure out why that ID is being assigned a value of `0`, maybe the method returns that when it can't find the object you requested? Don't trust the API to comply with its own restrictions!

Comment: Ahh i see. Thank you for the explanation.  It would be really stupid that the API would return a value of 0 and crash my Client before I have the ability to even view what was returned; I think I'll have to hackishly fix this.  There is hardly any documentation for this API unfortunately.

Comment: Unfortunately the 'hacking' method didn't seem to fix it at all.  Downloaded the WSDL, edited it, and added the reference based on that file.  Is it possible that this error could be fired on the server, and displayed back to me?

Comment: Accepted this as the answer.  Basically it came down to the Web Service not returning any helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

.NET is correct. "0" is not a valid value for the ID.